# Slow performance of timedelta methods

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Why does `.dt.days` take 100 times longer than `.dt.total_seconds()`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.date_range('2011-01-01 00:00:00', periods=1000000, freq='1H')})
df.a = df.a - pd.to_datetime('2011-01-01 00:00:00')
df.a.dt.days # 12 sec
df.a.dt.total_seconds() # 0.14 sec
```

Comment: A faster alternative is `days = pd.Series(df['a'].dt.values.astype('timedelta64[D]'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.dt.total_seconds` is basically just a multiplication, and can be performed at numpythonic speed:

```
def total_seconds(self):
    """
    Total duration of each element expressed in seconds.

    .. versionadded:: 0.17.0
    """
    return self._maybe_mask_results(1e-9 * self.asi8)
```

Whereas if we abort the `days` operation, we see it's spending its time in a slow listcomp with a getattr and a construction of Timedelta objects ([source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/tdi.py#L380)):

```
    360         else:
    361             result = np.array([getattr(Timedelta(val), m)
--> 362                                for val in values], dtype='int64')
    363         return result
    364
```

To me this screams "look, let's get it correct, and we'll cross the optimization bridge when we come to it."

Comment: these don't have many perf benchmarks - welcome to open an issue (PR even better!); these are all quite easy to optimize